# How do you compare strings in Perl?

Tags: string, perl

Practicing Perl for the first time today. I want to loop until a user types "quit". Entering "quit" does not stop and it is an infinite loop. Am I using string comparison wrong? I have this originally:

```
do 
{
    print "Enter a sentence or phrase to convert or 'quit': ";
    $choice = <STDIN>;  # user input variable
} while ($choice ne "quit");
```

I also tried creating a separate variable to store and check for in the do-while loop but still an infinite loop:

```
$quit = "quit";

do 
{
    print "Enter a sentence or phrase to convert to or 'quit': ";
    $choice = <STDIN>;  # init user input variable
    $dif = $quit ne $choice;
} while ($dif == 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$choice = <STDIN>` reads a line from stdin *including the newline at the end*.

You either need to check for `"quit\n"` or remove the newline with [`chomp`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp).

Comment: THANK YOU, coming from C++, I had no idea perl requires the newline marker to specify. Also thank you for explaining more how <STDIN> works

Comment: @Manny C++ also requires the newline character, `==` is exact. However, `cin` only reads up to the first whitespace character so it does not read the newline. `<filehandle>` reads the whole line.

Comment: @Manny Also, don't do this `while ($dif == 1)`. `$quit ne $choice` might happen to return 1, but it is documented to return true. Instead just check if it's true: `while($dif)`. It's a common mistake to check for 0 or 1 instead of false and true.

Comment: @Manny, Re "*I had no idea perl requires the newline marker to specify.*", To specify what, then end of the line? That's the definition of a line. Then end of the string? No, a LF does not indicate the end of a string, nor is it needed at the end of string. You read a line that contained a LF, and you didn't remove it (e.g. by using `chomp`). It has nothing to do with Perl